# "Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001." doesn't start in DevTools web

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, metro-bundler

I can't start a basic project with react native. In vscode terminal displays:

- Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
- Connecting to Metro bundler failed.

> Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed. at _waitForRunningAsync (C:@expo\xdl@57.9.28\src\Project.ts:1548:11) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

I follow this steps (vscode):

- npm install --global expo-cli
- expo init mobile (blank-typescript)
- cd mobile
- yarn start or expo start

What should I do?